# magento 1.9+ page shows 404 not found after 1.1 minutes

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, 404

I want to disable the 1.1 minutes limit for the page execution. I have a script that takes around 20 minutes to execute and need access from a url, but before the execution of the script is finished magento shows "WHOOPS, OUR BAD..." 404 error page.
How can I remove the one 1 minute limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by my hosting provider - they won't let me execute a script for more than one minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if there is a ~60 second limit defined in php.ini ([max_execution_time](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)) by using [phpinfo()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). If not, perhaps you could give us some details on the script's functions.